How to convert GMT to GMT + 09(KST) from jq result
jq result is below.
{date = 2024-06-07 00:00:00}
That is GMT.
How do I change timezone GMT+09(KST)?
Regards.

This may belong on Stack Overflow as its a programming question.

Your "jq result" isn't proper JSON.  Did you mean {"date": "2024-06-07 00:00:00"}?

Do you want something like jq '.date |= (strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") | .[3]+=9 | mktime | todate | sub("T";" ") | sub("Z"; " GMT+09(KST)") )'?

jq does support strflocaltime and if you are using gojq or a sufficiently recent version of the C implementation of jq, you could use that, e.g.:
TZ=Asia/Seoul gojq -n '"2024-06-07 00:00:00" 
  | strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  | mktime
  | strflocaltime("%FT%T %Z")'

yields "2024-06-07T09:00:00 KST"
If using the C implementation, please check the result.
An alternative would be to do the calculation yourself, e.g. along these lines:
jq -n '"2024-06-07 00:00:00" 
| strptime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
| .[3] += 9 
| mktime
| strftime("%FT%T KST")'


DST considerations
South Korea has historically observed daylight savings time at various periods, but as best I can tell has not done so since 1988.  The "TZ database" uses the letters "KDT" to refer to the periods when DST was observed in South Korea.  This means that using strflocaltime in conjunction with "TZ=Asia/Seoul" can result in "KDT" times.
For example, using the TZ technique outline above, gojq converts "1951-05-05 15:00:00" to "1951-05-06T01:00:00 KDT".

This may not work for half the year if the desired timezone uses daylight savings.

@glenn_jackman - The "S" in KST means "standard" and is in any case defined by GMT+9.  Daylight savings is another matter entirely, no?  Of course, if the question is: "what would the time be in Seoul, taking into account daylight savings adjustments?" that would require a more complex answer.

Apparently, except for an experiment from May 8 to October 9 in 1988, S. Korea does not have DST.

Re "The "S" in KST means "standard"", So why did you use TZ=Asia/Seoul, then? glenn is correct. Your two snippets do different things for time zones with DST. The first works, and the latter doesn't. (Oh, and if you believe that someone that says "EST" specifically means standard time and not America/New_York, you're going to be early for many appointments!)
